# Use fully qualified username in the NameID in wso2 identity server 5.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

While configuring a service provider in WSO2 identity server 5.1.0 Milestone 6 version, there is not option to select "Use fully qualified username in the NameID". Is this a bug or this configuration is moved to some other pages?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug. It has been moved under the section [`Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration` as 2 separate options.](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Local+and+Outbound+Authentication+for+a+Service+Provider)

- Use tenant domain in local subject identifier
- Use user store  domain in local subject identifier

Comment: Hi asanthi - I've edited a couple of your posts to fix up the markdown. I suggest you read over the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), especially regarding how to format links. There's also a "help" link in the header of the online editor (look for the `?`). You might also try using the provided tools for inserting links and images.